# Word for an enzymatic process

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

### Foreword:

I am developing a variable-processing program for my Computer Science research project.

One particular part of the program mimics the behavior of biological enzymes, except instead of catalyzing break downs and compositions of chemicals, its catalyzing break downs and compositions of variables (specifically arrays).

### The *process in question* is a 2 part process:

> - initiating process:
>
>   - *(in terms of enzymes:)* **breaks down** certain compounds **<kbd>into smaller compounds</kbd>**
>   - *(in terms of program:)* **fragments** certain variables (certain arrays) **<kbd>into fragments</kbd>**
> - finalizing process:
>
>   - *(in terms of enzymes:)* **combine** the smaller compounds **<kbd>into larger compounds different from the originals</kbd>** (*like mixing and matching the parts*)
>   - *(in terms of program:)* **combine** the fragment-variables **<kbd>into larger variables different from the originals</kbd>** (*like mixing and matching the parts*)

### The *process in question* all together:

> - *(in terms of enzymes:)* **breaks down** certain compounds **<kbd>into smaller compounds</kbd>**,
>   then **recombines** them **<kbd>into larger compounds that are different from the original large compounds</kbd>** 
>   (*like mixing and matching the parts*)
> - *(in terms of program:)* **fragments** certain variables (certain arrays) **<kbd>into fragments</kbd>** 
>   then **recombines** them **<kbd>into larger variables that are different from the original large variables</kbd>** 
>   (*like mixing and matching the parts*)

### What is the *process in question* called?

### Afternote:

I'm looking for a **name**, so the word could be a new word constructed from recognizable Latin or Germanic roots, and that would be an acceptable answer.

To get full coverage of an answer, I asked this question the [Chemistry SE site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61331/word-for-a-specific-enzymatic-process), [Stackoverflow SE site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165920/term-for-break-down-and-re-composition-of-arrays-in-programming), and this SE site.

Comment: the purpose of asking on the different sites is to get different types of feedback, so if you want to provide an answer on each site, please be considerate and don't dupe your answers. Answer with a different light and perspective. I am trying to get a full-coverage answer

Comment: As Mitch has said, "If [an answerable question, or answer, asks about] a recent neologism that other people use ... then [it is] on-topic. If it is looking for a 'neologism', or asking if a 'word' you just made up is OK, then off-topic because it is not answerable."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you are modelling enzymes I would suggest [decomposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/decompose) for the breaking down process (taking the chemistry definition) and [synthesis](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/synthesis?q=Synthesis) for the re-assembly process. To gain a single term to cover the entire process you could use **the decomposition/synthesis process** or possibly something like **the decomposyn process** as a neologism. You would, however, have to define "decomposyn" in your documentation.

As a matter of interest decomposition and synthesis are used to describe one of the ways of developing [CNC manufacturing systems](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212827115008793) so the terms are not entirely without precedent in an IT setting.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this neologism? in the case that I would want to do the reverse as well (start with synthesis, end with break down)?

Comment: As Mitch has said, "If [an answerable question, or answer, asks about] a recent neologism that other people use ... then [it is] on-topic. If it is looking for a 'neologism', or asking if a 'word' you just made up is OK, then off-topic because it is not answerable." The non-word _decomposyn_ is not admissible as an example of 'English ...usage'.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on one word, I would consider *assembly* and two sub-words, *disassembly* and *reassembly*, where *reassembly* does not necessarily result in what was originally *disassembled*.

From M-W:

> [*assembly*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assembly): the act of assembling something): the act of connecting together the parts of something (such as a machine) : the act of assembling something

**Addendum**: Enzymes merely catalyze reactions, i.e., make them go faster. Some enzymes "disassemble" while others "reassemble".

Comment: The issue with these is that disassemble, reassemble, and assemble are singular direction processes. The _processes-all-together_ I am describing is simplistically described as "go forward, then immediately reverse" or "reverse, then immediately go forward."

Comment: @DaMaxContent Tired tonight. Sorry. Sounds like nonsense to me. Every enzyme performs a "singular direction process". The only way you can have what you seem to be describing is with multiple enzymes acting in some sort of order. Maybe your enzyme analogy doesn't work.

Comment: Probably, but it was the closest anology at the time. As it is a breakdown-recompose process that needs to emphasize that the process forwards, then reverses and vice versa.